# Unable to delete an agent in Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I want to delete an agent in Actions-on-Google and I am told to first delete the agent in Dialogflow. In Dialogflow the agent is not listed. I have tried Dialogfull with all of my Google Accounts. The agent is still not listed.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54140339/dialogflow-agents-not-visible-in-the-console

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you see when you visit https://console.dialogflow.com/?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I staggered through a number of iterations before finally getting rid of the Project (which I think was the key). I could not repeat the process if you paid me but it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you have multiple Dialogflow projects?

You can switch projects in the top left corner - in the below example, by clicking the `expand-more` icon next to `greeting-card-store`:

[image: Switch Dialogflow projects]

Alternately, you can delete the entire Dialogflow project by clicking the `settings` icon next to the `expand-more` icon, then scrolling to the bottom of the `Settings > General` tab and clicking `Delete Agent`:

[image: Dialogflow - Delete Agent]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue earlier. I could fix it by starting a fresh, following these steps:

Logout from Dialogflow.
Login to your actions on google console.
Now in your action, go to the Actions and click on "edit in dialogflow".
[Actions navigation to dialogflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxhXT.png)
Now you will be asked to do a google login continue by clicking it.

**In Dialogflow**
Now the agent that will get displayed first, will be your agent and to validate. You can linked action's project id from project settings option
[Dialogflow agent settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iprW7.png)

Delete the agent in dialogflow.

And after that you can delete your action from google action console.

Sometimes, it may take few minutes to get reflected.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Open a cloud shell and set the project with `gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID`
2. `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list`
3. `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete NAME` (you will get NAME from step 2)

After these steps, I was able to remove my Actions projects and then my Cloud Console project.

From: https://support.google.com/a/thread/74530265/can-t-remove-google-cloud-project-due-to-dialogflow?hl=en